# How to plot contango/backwardation of successive contracts?

Tags: pine-script

I've been trying to plot the differences between futures contracts using pine script and can't seem to get it to work for any other combination than the current and next contract (e.g. `GC2!` - `GC1!`).

Example:

```
curr =
      month == 1 and year == 2019 ? "G2019" :
      month == 2 and year == 2019 ? "H2019" :
      // ...
      month == 11 and year == 2020 ? "Z2020" :
      month == 12 and year == 2020 ? "F2021" : ""
    
next =
      month == 1 and year == 2019 ? "H2019" :
      month == 2 and year == 2019 ? "J2019" :
      // ...
      month == 11 and year == 2020 ? "F2021" :
      month == 12 and year == 2020 ? "G2021" : ""

future_1 = security(syminfo.root + curr, "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
future_2 = security(syminfo.root + next, "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
contango = future_2 - future_1
    
// plot contango
```

The security function complains that a it cannot handle a `series[string]` but only a `string` as first argument and I cannot figure out how to convert them. The `tostring()` function doesn't seem to work with `series[string]`.

I know `curr` in this example could also be `GC2!` or `CL2!` or any other "next" futures contract, but the goal is to be able to visualize the contango amount between any two futures contracts.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately PineScript has many "issues" such as this one you've mentioned.
but good news...there are usually ways to work around them.

in your case, it may sound tedious...but try this:

calculate `security(...)` for each and every one of those options. (I know, its the least DRY code ever...but welcome to Pine Script)

```
G19 = security(syminfo.root + "G2019", "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
J19 = security(syminfo.root + "J2019", "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
...
F21 = security(syminfo.root + "F2021", "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
...
G21 = security(syminfo.root + "G2021", "D", close, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_off)
```

then after all that, use your chained ternary operators to determine which options to assign to `future_1/2` and then calculate `contango`

hope this helps